# Where are my server settings located (for backup purposes)

Tags: backup, centos5

I'm backing up files on my server, but I'd like to know the location of the most important server configuration files. I.E. - if I lose everything on my server, but I want to come back with the same configuration settings for PHP, MySQL, CPanel, WHM, DNS, etc... - what folders must I backup to be sure I can have a smooth transition back?

Of course, the DB and all web-app files are backed up in other methods.

Thanks for the help.

CentOS5, CPanel/WHM, MySQL, PHP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cPanel provides it's own backup facility, you can run it from shell/cron:

`# /scripts/cpbackup --force`

Configuration file resides in `/etc/cpbackup.conf`

MySQL database is usually stored in `/var/lib/mysql`, but it's safer to use `mysqldump`.

DNS configuration is located in `/etc/named`, but it's okay to backup `/var/named` too.

I also use `etckeeper` (can be installed from [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL)) to keep track of what was changed in /etc and optionally pull it with git/mercurial.

Answer (score 2):

In general, `/etc` is the most important directory.  In any Red Hat type system (as CentOS is), you'll find some settings in `/etc/sysconfig`, but that's pretty limited.  Back up all of `/etc` to be safe.